# 1D convolutional neural network validation improvement

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I created 1D CNN in Keras, but I'm having issues with validation loss and accuracy.
I have 24k records, 22 features. Is my model overfitting or what is going on so validation loss and accuracy is inconsistent? They rise and drop over epochs.
Here is my model

```
#model
n_obs, feature, depth = X_train.shape
batch_size = 20
kernel_size = 2
pool_size = 2
filters = 16


inp = Input(shape=(feature, depth))
C = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1)(inp)

C11 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(C)
A11 = Activation("relu")(C11)
C12 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(A11)
S11 = Add()([C12, C])
A12 = Activation("relu")(S11)
M11 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size, strides=2)(A12)


C21 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(M11)
A21 = Activation("relu")(C21)
C22 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(A21)
S21 = Add()([C22, M11])
A22 = Activation("relu")(S11)
M21 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size, strides=2)(A22)


C31 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(M21)
A31 = Activation("relu")(C31)
C32 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(A31)
S31 = Add()([C32, M21])
A32 = Activation("relu")(S31)
M31 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size, strides=2)(A32)


C41 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(M31)
A41 = Activation("relu")(C41)
C42 = Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=1, padding='same')(A41)
S41 = Add()([C42, M31])
A42 = Activation("relu")(S41)
M41 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size, strides=2)(A42)

F1 = Flatten()(M41)

D1 = Dense(21)(F1)
A6 = Activation("relu")(D1)
D2 = Dense(16)(A6)
D22 = Dense(8)(D2)
D3 = Dense(2)(D22)
A7 = Softmax()(D3)

model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=A7)

lrate = LearningRateScheduler(0.001)
adam = Adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    epochs=200, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    verbose=2, 
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
                    callbacks=[lrate])
```

[image: Validation loss and accuracy]

Training set is about 15k records, valid 1.5k and test 6k records. Although test set achieve 96% correct classification I'm wondering if this validation inconsistent behaviour is something I should fix.
What can I do about it?

EDIT: example data
[image]

Comment: First thing that catches my eye is the small size of your validation set. I'd suggest to split your non-test data into something more balanced like 80/20 for train/val.

Comment: How many output classes do you have? Can we get a glimpse of the data to better help you. I am thinking that the current model is too complex for the little amount of data you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers. I will try go 80/20 train/valid sets. I also added example data, last column is class assigned to record. I have only 2 output classes. Also i removed 1 feature because it was duplication of other feature.